# Running JBoss in Windows Azure

Tags: jboss, azure

I have found an example of running Tomcat in Windows Azure, but JBoss seems to be a bit trickier. Has anyone succeeded in running JBoss in Windows Azure, and if so, what should I do to get it running?

I would like to know if JBoss can be run in a worker role, not the VM role which is currently in beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying it and asking questions as you get roadblocked.  Most "does this run in Azure" questions are answered with "yes", but full-fledged examples and guides are going to be sparse as the platform is very new.  So be the guy who writes it :)

You have two options with something like this:

1.) Run a worker role that invokes and runs similar to a windows service. (most tomcat on azure guides approach this way)

2.) Use a Azure Startup task to install, configure, start jBoss as a windows service and/or on top of tomcat

With the addition of full-trust, startup tasks, RDP, and eventually even VMrole .. anything that can run on a Windows 2008 server can run on Azure.   So try installing on a Windows box, document those steps, then 1 by 1, figure out the "azure way" to accomplish those tasks.  Approached this way, the initial setup will likely be pretty simple.  From there, you'll learn a lot about Azure's offerings and can probably even make some changes to better leverage the platform for JBoss needs.

Once you get up there and have issues, ask away and you're more likely to find direct answers by the audience of MVPs, Azure team members, and cloud geeks here vs just a generic "have you done this" answer.

Comment: We used your approach and eventually got it to work based an the Tomcat guide that's avaialable from Microsoft.